# Question accidentally marked as community wiki

Tags: support, reputation, specific-question, community-wiki

This question, [Dealing with ugly SQL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919253), was mistakenly made community wiki.

The author of the question admits it was a mistake (see comments).

> Why was this marked community wiki? – Asaph 4 hours ago
>   Asaph, oops, my mistake. I don't see an option to undo it. – Artem 3 hours ago

Can this question be taken out of community wiki mode and can earned reputation for answers be retroactively applied?

Comment: Just leave it the way it is. There will be other questions and answers that will earn you rep.

Comment: @I hate haikus: I guess I don't have a choice in the matter :)

Comment: Why won't earned reputation for answers be retroactively applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CW is one-way. Looks like charity work for you.

Answer (score 2):

It was no accident. Read the question intent:

> How do others here deal with [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Do people ever use [...]

Style of question fits the community wiki.

The asker only said it was an accident when one of the comments badgered about it. Probably because they were missing out on rep.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with your interpretation of the asker's intentions. My comment was hardly badgering: "Why was this marked community wiki?" (Of course I was after the rep! What's so wrong about that?) And the asker responded with "Asaph, oops, my mistake. I don't see an option to undo it.".

Comment: It's a subjective question. One where they were looking to see what else other people did. Getting to know you in a way. Community wiki.